# How to listen to the deletion of files before deleting them in Android

Tags: java, android, c++, kotlin

I want to make an application of the "recycle bin" type, but I can't find any information on *how to intercept files before deleting*.
Anything at all. Or at least where I should look.

Comment: for the whole system? You can't do that

Comment: but, the Dumpster app does this

Comment: That App scans "hard disk" sectors for REALLY DELETED files. It's not a recycle-bin App but a RECOVERY Tool for "already destroyed files". Files, in the Storage, are just "marked" as deleted but their bytes still persist on the "disk" for a lot of time, and this App recovers them if same "disk area" is not overwritten in the meanwhile.

Comment: Sounds like dumpster is a nasty hack:https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-does-the-Dumpster-recycle-bin-for-Android-catch-up-deleted-files can't imagine it does much for the performance or battery life of your phone

Comment: @emandt, i tested Dumpster - This only works if the files were deleted while the application was running: if you delete the file while the application is disabled, and then run it, it will not detect the deleted file.
Even the "Dumpster" notification says that it intercepted the deleted file.

Comment: There could be different causes for this. The first is because this App could OBSERVES folder changes and store them in a Database. FileObservers, however, works with Permissions so if you App don't have right Permissions that folder cannot be observed. On newer Android 10/11+ a non-system-App cannot read/write/observe folders that it don't owns. The only workaroud is to Target a lower SDK (< 29) but it cannot be uploaded in the Store starting from few months ago. Please read documentation for FileObserver and Android 10+ to know if you can do what you try to achieve.